# await does not wait until the file download finish in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, asynchronous, async-await

In my app I download the image from URL then save it in local directory. Then next iteration / next app run, the app will just fetch it from local directory.

I download a file from URL like this:

```
Future<Uint8List> getImageFromCloud(String url) async {

   final response = await Client().get(url);

   return response.bodyBytes;
}
```

Then I saved the downloaded bytes into a file like this:

```
 static Future<File> saveFileAsBytes(Uint8List bytes, String path, String filename) async {
    // Getting App's local directory
    final Directory localRootDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final String filePath = p.join(localRootDirectory.path, path, filename);

    final file = await File(filePath).create(recursive: true);

    final imageFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return imageFile;
  }
```

The page state is handled by a bloc like this:

```
Stream<PageState> initializeBloc(String url) async* {
   final bytes = await getImageFromCloud(url);
   final imageFile = await saveFileAsBytes(bytes, path, filename);

   yield PageReadyState(imageFile);

}
```

Later in the page's code we use the imageFile for CircleAvatar like this:

```
Widget onPageReadyState(PageReadyState state) {
   
// -- Some code

   CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: FileImage(state.imageFile),
   );

// -- Some code

}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
   BlocBuilder<PageBloc, PageState>(builder: (context, state) {

      if (state is PageUninitializedState) {
        return onPageUninitializedState();
      } else if (state is PageReadyState) {
        return onPageReadyState(state);
      } else return onLoadingPage();
}
```

But this always crash with `Exception: Invalid image data`.
This is strange because the bloc has waited for the process of download and writing the file locally to finish before yielding the `PageReadyState` state.

Then I found out that the file size being returned from `getImageFromCloud` is not its full size (in one of the case it was 106 while the full file size is 21480). Consequently caused the crash with the `CircleAvatar`.

Then I run the app the second time and this time I read the same file from local (because it was downloaded on the first run), and the file exist with its full size. This means that **the first time it downloads the file, the download was still on going in the background when the function returns the File object to the `CircleAvatar`, even when I have used the `await` keyword here.** And of course the second time, the file already exist in local directory and thus no crash.

I hope the explanation is clear.

So do you know what am I missing here? Why the `await` does not wait for the whole file to be done downloading before returning from the function?

*Note: tested with different image files with different size, it always return the file with size 106 at first download*

Comment: getImageFromCloud() method is returning Future, but not marked as async?

Comment: sorry my bad, typo error when writing this question. But it has `async` in the real code. question fixed

Answer (score 0):

```dart
static Future<File> saveFileAsBytes(Uint8List bytes, String path, String filename) async {
    // Getting App's local directory
    final Directory localRootDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final String filePath = p.join(localRootDirectory.path, path, filename);

    final file = await File(filePath).createSync(recursive: true);

    final imageFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return imageFile;
  }
```

try createSync instead of create

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).